# Switching between basic and SAML Authentication mechanism in Tomcat 8 - Keycloak

Tags: basic-authentication, saml-2.0, tomcat8, keycloak

I am securing a Webapp (war) that lives on Tomcat 8.  I am using Keycloak as my Authentication Server.

The previous webapp we secured were using Servlet Filters and we could make it switch between authentication mechanism programmatically.

But now Keycloak is a requirement.. For normal authentication keycloak requires us to modify the Context.xml and specify it as follow:

For Normal Authentication:

```
<Context path="/your-context-path">
    <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>
</Context>
```

For SAML:

```
<Context path="/your-context-path">
    <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.saml.tomcat.SamlAuthenticatorValve"/>
</Context>
```

My question is, is there a way to switch between these 2 programmatically ?  Could we specify more than one Valve there ?